# Making Image glow at certain points when it doesn't get any values in Real Time Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, libraries

I've got a few sensors that I'll be placing on a chair and when there is weight on those sensors, it gives a reading. Should one of the sensors fail to detect any weight or should there be a drastic change in the readings, the hardware prototype of mine would have a LED glow red, else it would be green.

Now I intend to make a graphical representation of this, by having an image of a human being with some points "mapped" or "placed" to certain parts, say head, chest, arms, legs, so as when the sensors fail to send proper data, that part of the human image, to which the variable "mapped" to is receiving no data or an abnormal change, should start to glow, or turn to a different color. The glowing be in real time, fade in and out. (even a static blurring would work)

So far, the hardware works fine... but I'm not sure about how I should try to implement this... getting the data I've used MQTT, but displaying the data I'm not very sure. Would it be appropriate to display this on a website or would it be better on an app using Kivy with many of the Python libraries like TKinter or Qt..? Or is it something to do with Image Processing?

Any suggestion will help, thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could mock up an example of what you mean and [edit] it into your question?

Comment: What do you mean by *"glowing"*? Fading in and out? Or  static blurred highlights?

Comment: What are you using to make the GUI - is it a web page? Or Qt? Or Tkinter?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've edited the question, any suggestions would help, thanks!